# Reading and Writing to file is not finishing until after the program finishes

Tags: c

What my program is doing is that it takes 3 commands such as `wc` `md5sum` etc, commands that operate on files from Linux. It also takes a file path name as input as well. It creates forks for each command and then it stores the command output into a file. After all these complete I print out the command output and result time etc in `main`.

The problem I am having is that commands that take longer to run such as `wc` on a big file, the command output isn't being saved into the file until after the program is completely finished. Therefore it isn't printing out in my results.

I am not sure why this is happening because the parent should print results until child processes are complete. I need some help with this or a point in the right direction. I would prefer just storing the command output in a `char *` instead of writing to file, but I can't figure out how to redirect the output to a char buffer for return. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXIN 255
#define SEP "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

int currProc = 0;
const char *procStrFin[] = {"First process finished...", "Second process finished...", "Third process finished..."};
int p1file = 0;
int p2file = 0;
int p3file = 0;

struct Response
{
  int pid1;
  int pid2;
  int pid3;
  char *result1;
  char *result2;
  char *result3;
  double time1;
  double time2;
  double time3;
};

//Fork and run command with args
struct Response runCmd(char *command1, char *command2, char *command3, char *file)
{
  struct Response res;
  res.result1 = "";
  res.result2 = "";
  res.result3 = "";

  /*
    Command 1 Parse
    */
  char *fullCommand1 = strcat(command1, " ");
  fullCommand1 = strcat(fullCommand1, file);
  //Create an array of split commands for arg1 of execvp
  char *p1s = strtok(fullCommand1, " ");     //start token pointer
  char *splitCommand1[strlen(fullCommand1)]; //init split command array based on size of full command
  int i1 = 0;                                //init counter
  while (p1s != NULL)                        //Loop through each word and store in array
  {
    splitCommand1[i1++] = p1s;
    p1s = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  splitCommand1[i1] = NULL; //NULL terminate array

  /*
    Command 2 Parse
    */
  char *fullCommand2 = strcat(command2, " ");
  fullCommand2 = strcat(fullCommand2, file);
  //Create an array of split commands for arg1 of execvp
  char *p2s = strtok(fullCommand2, " ");     //start token pointer
  char *splitCommand2[strlen(fullCommand2)]; //init split command array based on size of full command
  int i2 = 0;                                //init counter
  while (p2s != NULL)                        //Loop through each word and store in array
  {
    splitCommand2[i2++] = p2s;
    p2s = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  splitCommand2[i2] = NULL; //NULL terminate array

  /*
    Command 3 Parse
    */
  char *fullCommand3 = strcat(command3, " ");
  fullCommand3 = strcat(fullCommand3, file);
  //Create an array of split commands for arg1 of execvp
  char *p3s = strtok(fullCommand3, " ");     //start token pointer
  char *splitCommand3[strlen(fullCommand3)]; //init split command array based on size of full command
  int i3 = 0;                                //init counter
  while (p3s != NULL)                        //Loop through each word and store in array
  {
    splitCommand3[i3++] = p3s;
    p3s = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  splitCommand3[i3] = NULL; //NULL terminate array

  /*
    FORKS
    */
  double time_spent1 = 0.0;
  double time_spent2 = 0.0;
  double time_spent3 = 0.0;
  clock_t begin = clock();
  clock_t end;

  int p1 = fork();
  if (p1 < 0)
  {
    //Output redirect to file and run command
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    p1file = open("p1.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
    printf("CMD1:[SHELL 1] STATUS CODE=-1");
  }
  else if (p1 == 0) //P1 Controlled
  {
    //Output redirect to file and run command
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    p1file = open("p1.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
    execvp(splitCommand1[0], splitCommand1);
  }
  else //Parent Controlled
  {
    end = clock();
    time_spent1 += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%s\n", procStrFin[currProc]);
    res.pid1 = p1;
    res.time1 = time_spent1;
    currProc++;
    int p2 = fork();
    if (p2 < 0)
    {
      //Output redirect to file and run command
      close(STDOUT_FILENO);
      p2file = open("p2.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
      printf("CMD2:[SHELL 2] STATUS CODE=-1");
    }
    else if (p2 == 0) //P2 Controlled
    {
      close(STDOUT_FILENO);
      p2file = open("p2.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
      execvp(splitCommand2[0], splitCommand2);
    }
    else //Parent Controlled
    {
      end = clock();
      time_spent2 += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      printf("%s\n", procStrFin[currProc]);
      res.pid2 = p2;
      res.time2 = time_spent2;
      currProc++;
      int p3 = fork();
      if (p3 < 0)
      {
        //Output redirect to file and run command
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        p3file = open("p3.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
        printf("CMD3:[SHELL 3] STATUS CODE=-1");
      }
      else if (p3 == 0) //P3 Controlled
      {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        p3file = open("p3.temp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
        execvp(splitCommand3[0], splitCommand3);
      }
      else //Parent Controlled
      {
        end = clock();
        time_spent3 += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%s\n", procStrFin[currProc]);
        res.pid3 = p3;
        res.time3 = time_spent3;
        int parent = wait(NULL); //Wait on children
        return res;
      }
    }
  }
}

//Quick max function
float max(float num1, float num2)
{
  return (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
}

/* Take file path and read from file*/
char *readFromFile(char *filename)
{
  char *buffer = 0;
  long length;
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb"); //was "rb"

  if (f)
  {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer)
    {
      fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
  }
  buffer[length] = '\0';
  // for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  //     printf("buffer[%d] == %c\n", i, buffer[i]);
  // }
  //printf("buffer = %s\n", buffer);

  return buffer;
}

//Deletes file
int deleteFile(char *filename)
{
  if (remove(filename) == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}

//MAIN
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char buf[MAXIN];
  //Command 1
  printf("Welcome to MASH!\nmash-1>");
  fgets(buf, MAXIN, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; //remove newlines
  char *cmd1 = strdup(buf);

  //Command 2
  printf("mash-2>");
  fgets(buf, MAXIN, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; //remove newlines
  char *cmd2 = strdup(buf);

  //Command 3
  printf("mash-3>");
  fgets(buf, MAXIN, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; //remove newlines
  char *cmd3 = strdup(buf);

  // File Command
  printf("file>");
  fgets(buf, MAXIN, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; //remove newlines
  char *fileCmd = strdup(buf);

  struct Response response = runCmd(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, fileCmd);

  //Command Results Output
  int pre = 12;
  int cmd1Len = 80 - (strlen(cmd1) + pre);
  int cmd2Len = 80 - (strlen(cmd2) + pre);
  int cmd3Len = 80 - (strlen(cmd3) + pre);
  char cmd1Sep[80] = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < cmd1Len; i++)
  {
    strcat(cmd1Sep, "-");
  }
  char cmd2Sep[80] = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < cmd2Len; i++)
  {
    strcat(cmd2Sep, "-");
  }
  char cmd3Sep[80] = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < cmd3Len; i++)
  {
    strcat(cmd3Sep, "-");
  }

  //Get file input
  char *cmd1Out = readFromFile("p1.temp");
  char *cmd2Out = readFromFile("p2.temp");
  char *cmd3Out = readFromFile("p3.temp");

  printf("-----CMD 1: %s%s\n", cmd1, cmd1Sep);
  printf("%sResult took:%fms\n", cmd1Out, response.time1);
  printf("-----CMD 2: %s%s\n", cmd2, cmd2Sep);
  printf("%sResult took:%fms\n", cmd2Out, response.time2);
  printf("-----CMD 3: %s%s\n", cmd3, cmd3Sep);
  printf("%sResult took:%fms\n", cmd3Out, response.time3);
  printf("%s\n", SEP);
  printf("Parent PID: %d\n", getpid());
  printf("Children process IDs: %d %d %d.\n", response.pid1, response.pid2, response.pid3);
  printf("Total elapsed time:%fms\n", max(response.time3, max(response.time2, response.time1)));

  //Delete Files
  // deleteFile("p1.temp");
  // deleteFile("p2.temp");
  // deleteFile("p3.temp");
  return 0;
}
```

Example Output:

```
Welcome to MASH!
mash-1>wc
mash-2>md5sum
mash-3>grep -c the
file>big.log
First process finished...
Second process finished...
Third process finished...
-----CMD 1: wc------------------------------------------------------------------
Result took:0.000070ms
-----CMD 2: md5sum--------------------------------------------------------------
Result took:0.000120ms
-----CMD 3: grep----------------------------------------------------------------
40
Result took:0.000160ms
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent PID: 7664
Children process IDs: 7665 7666 7667.
Total elapsed time:0.000160ms
```

Comment: There's a good deal of triple-repeated code in there that cries out "put me in a function!".  You should probably have a simpler `struct OneResponse` that contains the PID, result, time, and then use an array of those (`struct Response { struct OneResponse r[3]; };` for example) and that should simplify the code a lot.  You have less 'only the member name changes' printing to do.

Comment: yes i'm aware. was going to do code cleanup after

Comment: Inside the `runCmd()` function, you can't do `char *fullCommand3 = strcat(command3, " ");
  fullCommand3 = strcat(fullCommand3, file);` because the string space that `command3` points at is only big enough for the initial string, not the space and the file name too.  That alone leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should also ensure that if `execvp()` fails — if it returns — that the child process exits (preferably after reporting an error).

Answer (score 0):

from a man page:

> The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until **one** of its children terminates.

you need to use `waitpid` with `-1` as the first argument to wait for all children to finish.

Comment: The POSIX specification of [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) says: _If `pid` is equal to `(pid_t)-1`, status is requested for any child process. In this respect, `waitpid()` is then equivalent to `wait()`._  You need to loop until `waitpid()` indicates there are no more processes to wait for — by returning `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:

```
int parent = wait(NULL); //Wait on children
```

This waits on one child, not all children.  The shell `wait` command is different from the `wait()` system call in this respect.

You need, therefore, something like:

```
int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
```

This loops until there are no more children.  A possible alternative would be to use `waitpid()` to wait for each child in turn, but you'd … well, to be sensible, you'd need to store the pids of the children in an array instead of three numbered variables, but you could do it with three variables.

Your code needs to use far more functions and have far less repetition of everything three times with the names of the variables changing.  Handling 2 or 4 or 5 children should be as simple as handling 3 — with the current code structure, that is anything but trivial.

For example, if you created a function:

```
static void wait_for_pid(int pid)
{
    int corpse;
    int status;
    if ((corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) > 0)
        printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to wait for PID %d\n", pid);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

You could then use:

```
wait_for_pid(res.pid1);
wait_for_pid(res.pid2);
wait_for_pid(res.pid3);
```

That's not great, but it is better than writing out the `waitpid()` code with error checking 3 times.

Your timing code is suspect too.  It is pretty much guaranteed not to be giving the correct results.  You stop the clock on process 2 before you've even launched process 3, but that doesn't mean that process 2 has even got going, much less finished.